# "No parameterless constructor defined for this object" error after implementing Unit of Work

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have implemented Unit Of Work and facing following the error, earlier the project implemented well when I just implemented Repository. This is the error I'm getting in my Browser (Google Chrome Version 90.0.4430.212 (Official Build) (64-bit)):

> Server Error in '/' Application.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

> Source Error:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

> Stack Trace:

> [MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object.]
> System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +122
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +239
> System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +85
> System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +55

> [InvalidOperationException: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'OfficeWork.Controllers.PopulationsController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.]
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerActivator.Create(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +178
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) +80
> System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +102
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +188
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +48
> System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
> System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +105
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step) +50
> System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +163

> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4330.0

"IUnitOfWork" interface:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    interface IUnitOfWork
    {
        IStudentRepository StudentRepository { get; }
        IStudentRepositoryRole StudentRepositoryRole { get; }
        Task<bool> SaveAsync();
    }
}
```

UnitOfWork:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly PopulationDBContext dc;
        public UnitOfWork(PopulationDBContext dc)
        {
            this.dc = dc;
        }
        public IStudentRepository StudentRepository =>
            new StudentRepository(dc);

        public IStudentRepositoryRole StudentRepositoryRole =>
            new StudentRepositoryRole(dc);

        public async Task<bool> SaveAsync()
        {
            return await dc.SaveChangesAsync() > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
using OfficeWork.DAL;
using OfficeWork.ED;
using OfficeWork.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;


namespace OfficeWork.Controllers
{
    public class PopulationsController : Controller
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;
        Password password_hiding = new Password();
     

         PopulationsController(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
            
            this.uow = uow;
        }



       

        //Direct to homepage after logging in
        public ActionResult HomePage(int id)
        {

            Population population = uow.StudentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
            return View(population);
        }


        //Controller used to update existing information
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdatePopulation(Population std, int id)
        {
            
            {
                Population updatestd = uow.StudentRepository.GetStudentByID(id);
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(std.Email)) { updatestd.Email = std.Email; }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(std.FirstName)) { updatestd.FirstName = std.FirstName; }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(std.LastName)) { updatestd.LastName = std.LastName; }
                { updatestd.MobileNumber = std.MobileNumber; }
                { updatestd.DateOfBirth = std.DateOfBirth; }
                 { updatestd.Password =password_hiding.encrypt(std.Password); }
                uow.StudentRepository.UpdateStudent(updatestd);
                uow.SaveAsync();
            }
            return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        //Controller used to direct to the Edit page
        public ActionResult Edit(int val)
        {
            Population p = uow.StudentRepository.GetStudentByID(val);
            p.Password = password_hiding.Decrypt(p.Password);

            return View(p);
        }


        //Main page is the page consisting of user details
        public ActionResult UserDetails(int val)
        {
          

            Population std = uow.StudentRepository.GetStudentByID(val);

            return View(std);
        }


        public ActionResult SignIn(int? id)
        {
            return View();
        }

        
        //This post Sign in controller helps in authenticating user and redirecting it the user details page
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SignIn(string email, string password)
        {
            var new_pas =password_hiding.encrypt(password);
            Population dbs = uow.StudentRepository.GetStudentByEmailPass(email, new_pas);
                int id = dbs.ID;
           
            Role ro = uow.StudentRepositoryRole.GetStudentByID(id);
            if(ro!=null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Admin");
            }
                if (dbs != null)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("HomePage/"+id);
                }
                else
                {
                    return View();
                }
            
        }


        public ActionResult SignUp()
        {
            return View();
        }


        // This POST controller is used to sign up. It takes values(Email,FirstName,LastName,MobileNumber,DateOfBirth,Password) from the page and add it to the database.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult SignUp([Bind(Include = "Email,FirstName,LastName,MobileNumber,DateOfBirth,Password")] Population population)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                population.Password =password_hiding.encrypt(population.Password);
                uow.StudentRepository.InsertStudent(population);
                uow.SaveAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("SignIn");
            }

            return View(population);
        }


        //If Username: anirudhrawat1@gmail.com and Password:Solution or Username: arnav@gmail.com and Password: Hello is entered to SIGN IN page then it will direct the user to List of entries.
        public ActionResult Admin()
        {
            IEnumerable<Population> students = uow.StudentRepository.GetStudents();
                          
            return View(students);
        }
    }
}
```

"StudentRepository" repository file of "Population":

```
using OfficeWork.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    public class StudentRepository : IStudentRepository, IDisposable
    {
        private PopulationDBContext  context;

        public StudentRepository(PopulationDBContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Population> GetStudents()
        {
            return context.Populations.ToList();
        }

        public Population GetStudentByID(int id)
        {
            return context.Populations.Find(id);
        }
        public Population GetStudentByEmailPass(string email, string password)
        {
            return context.Populations.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email == email && e.Password == password);
        }

        public void InsertStudent(Population student)
        {
            context.Populations.Add(student);
        }

        public void DeleteStudent(int studentID)
        {
            Population student = context.Populations.Find(studentID);
            context.Populations.Remove(student);
        }

        public void UpdateStudent(Population student)
        {
            context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

     

        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

"IStudentRepository" interface file:

```
using OfficeWork.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    public interface IStudentRepository : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Population> GetStudents();
        Population GetStudentByID(int studentId);
        void InsertStudent(Population student);
        Population GetStudentByEmailPass(string email, string password);
        void DeleteStudent(int studentID);
        void UpdateStudent(Population student);
      
    }
}
```

"StudentRepositoryRole" repository file of "Role":

```
using OfficeWork.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    public class StudentRepositoryRole : IStudentRepositoryRole, IDisposable
    {
        private PopulationDBContext context;

        public StudentRepositoryRole(PopulationDBContext context)
        {
            this.context = context;
        }

        public IEnumerable<Role> GetStudents()
        {
            return context.Roles.ToList();
        }

        public Role GetStudentByID(int id)
        {
            return context.Roles.Find(id);
        }

        public void InsertStudent(Role student)
        {
            context.Roles.Add(student);
        }

        public void DeleteStudent(int studentID)
        {
            Role student = context.Roles.Find(studentID);
            context.Roles.Remove(student);
        }

        public void UpdateStudent(Role student)
        {
            context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }


        private bool disposed = false;

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!this.disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    context.Dispose();
                }
            }
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}
```

"IstudentRepositoryRole" interface file:

```
using OfficeWork.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    public interface IStudentRepositoryRole : IDisposable
    {
        IEnumerable<Role> GetStudents();
        Role GetStudentByID(int studentId);
        void InsertStudent(Role student);
        void DeleteStudent(int studentID);
        void UpdateStudent(Role student);
      
    }
}
```

PopulationDBContext:

```
using OfficeWork.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace OfficeWork.DAL
{
    public class PopulationDBContext : DbContext
    {
     
        public DbSet<Population> Populations { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is now injecting `IUnitOfWork`, but it looks like you haven't set up a dependency injection framework to know how to create one of those. when instantiating your constructor.

Comment: Could you please help me with how to set up "dependency injection"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that's not something I can help with in a Q&A format like StackOverflow. Spend some time researching dependency injection in asp.net-mvc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are right dependency injection was the issue. It took me bit long but now dependency injection is clear to me. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue was "dependency injection".

```
 private readonly IUnitOfWork uow;
         PopulationsController(IUnitOfWork uow)
        {
          this.uow = uow;
        }
```

I installed Unity.Mvc5 from Nuget Packages. I has in-built configuration to make dependency injections.
After adding Unity.Mvc5. It created UnityConfig.cs file in App_start automatically.

1)Add "container.RegisterType<Interface, Repository>();" in UnityConfig.cs

2)Add "UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();" in Global.asax.cs.